# Encoding php and python?

Tags: php, python

I wrote code that sends a query from php to a python script(some variable) and the python script does some things and returns some str. But this string is not valid! It has many question marks. I know that this problem appears when the encoding is not valid, but all files I'm using have the format `utf-8`.

My php file:

```
$search = $_POST["search"];
$search = shell_exec('get.py ' . $search);
 print($search);
```

And as result I see this `������������`. Python script code:

```
import sys
import pymorphy2


morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

word = sys.argv[1]

word = morph.parse(word)[0]
i = 0
result = ""
while i < len(word):
    result = result + " " + word.make_agree_with_number(i).word
    i = i + 1
print (result)
```

Some interesting things: all (2) files are in `utf-8`. In the python script I use coding `utf-8` and it is not help. In php I use the `iconv()` function to change encoding, and use the `mb_detect_encoding` function to detect what the encoding is now. It shows `utf-8`. Please help me to make my encoding valid!

My version of python is `3.5`, and I use `.htaccess`.

Comment: Does your shell support utf-8?

Comment: you might want to at a minimum put a shebang (#!/usr/bin/env python) at the top of your python file or do shell_exec('python get.py '  ; otherwise on Unix/Linux, doing shell_exec is going to try to run your application as a shell script

Comment: this is almost definitely due to your terminal not supporting UTF-8; use `urxvt` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be having this problem, and can narrow down what the problem is by using a *minimal* example:

In `call_python.php`:

```
<?php 

$result = shell_exec('python called_python.py');
print("Python reports: ".$result);
```

In `called_python.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("I am a banana!")
```

We can see the result:

```
$ php call_python.php 
Python reports: I am a banana!
```

I'm using a `bash` shell on a Mac system. If the above works for you, you know the problem is what you're doing inside the code. If not, you know that it has to do with the transport between the two scripts.